# GAE deployment throwing Error Response: [13] The system encountered a fatal error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

Encountering problem when deploying Node/React application to App engine using the command: `gcloud app deploy --quiet --no-promote --no-stop-previous-version --version={VERSION_NUMBER}`. This didn't happen before with the previous deployments only until today.

I've also checked the deployment and application logs in Cloud Console and there are no errors. This code is also working on my local and there are no changes to the configuration so I don't know where the problem is coming from. Also did deploy the reverted code but the error is still the same.

app.yaml file:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 2
  disk_size_gb: 15
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Here's the logs when running the debug mode: Result:

> { "done": true, "error": { "code": 13, "message": "The system encountered a fatal error" }, "metadata": { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1", "createVersionMetadata": { "cloudBuildId": "4e46d51e-f408-479e-ad06-81cd794d9028" }, "endTime": "2022-05-25T15:41:26.285Z", "insertTime": "2022-05-25T15:10:10.933Z", "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion", "target": "{OMITTED}", "user": "{OMITTED}" }, "name": "apps/{OMITTED}/operations/e9d94daa-055b-4903-8cbf-372df1ce5c3c" } Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed. DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] The system encountered a fatal error Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 987, in Execute resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args) File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 809, in Run resources = command_instance.Run(args) File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\app\deploy.py", line 127, in Run return deploy_util.RunDeploy( File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 692, in RunDeploy aiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone return not poller.IsDone(operation) File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 182, in IsDone raise OperationError(requests.ExtractErrorMessage(googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [13] The system encountered a fatal error ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] The system encountered a fatal error

I've submitted a ticket to GCP support but haven't responded yet. Wondering if someone here has encountered this error before and the resolution.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?  

This just happened to me.  

ReactJS project, using the standard service with nodejs14.  Never had an issue deploying in over a year.   My app.yaml and package.json have not changed.  


So far I've tried to update my google SDK, then tried the following:

gcloud config set interactive/hidden true
gcloud app update --service-account xxxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com  


Same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/201556420#comment5), The **Google Support Team** suggests using the commands below to fix the issue:

```
gcloud config set interactive/hidden true
```

then:

```
gcloud app update --service account=your_project_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I raised a ticket to Google Support team and they came back saying it was due to the latest release of GAE that caused it. They said they have reverted the change and it is now working as expected.